# What are some countries where you can be imprisoned for reading or owning a Bible?

Tags: bible, persecution

Growing up Christian, I would always hear of far away countries where people would be imprisoned for reading the Bible. Today I wondered about that. Are there really any countries that imprison people for reading the Bible, or is it perhaps groups religious groups within these countries that will persecute Christians?

I found a [similar question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9351/in-what-countries-is-it-illegal-to-own-a-bible-the-most-banned-book-in-the-worl) about countries where the Bible is banned, but it seems like there is not a single country that has a total ban, other than North Korea, which bans *all* religious texts, not just the Bible.

Comment: Some countries spring to mind but it would be good to have a documented catalogue available, if such a thing exists or can be collated. Excellent question. +1.

Comment: Also of note is that if a country is so oppressive that it will imprison you for a mere possession of a Bible, they might not even have an official law about it, or they might even officially deny it, to keep up appearances. Such countries are known to try to pretend that they are free and democratic, and despite no law explicitly forbidding something, you can still be imprisoned or tortured on made-up charges (or no charges at all) if you do something they don't like.

Comment: "...or is it perhaps religious groups within these countries that will persecute Christians?" In some of the middle-eastern nations where the national government is controlled by a religious group, and that government does not stop (or do much of anything about it) members of the religious group from imprisoning, torturing, or executing Christians, then it essentially is almost as if the government itself is sponsoring the activity. More middle-eastern nations should be listed in answers here, as their actions speak louder than their official words.

Comment: Not really an answer but more of a resource really - take a look at https://www.opendoorsuk.org/persecution/countries/ - they update each year with the top 50 countries where Christians are persecuted

Answer (score 22):

Countries which ban the possession of the bible include:

**Saudi Arabia**

> At present, the Bible has been banned in **Saudi Arabia**. In a number of countries, bible translation, distribution, sale or promotion is prohibited or made difficult, and the Bible may be considered extremist materials. Historically, some countries banned the Bible in certain languages or versions. The Bible in Spanish was prohibited in Spain from the sixteenth until the nineteenth century. In 1234, King James I of Aragon ordered the burning of Bibles in the vernacular. In 2015, Russia banned import of the Jehovah's Witnesses' New World Translation of the Holy Scriptures. - [List of books banned by governments](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_books_banned_by_governments)

**North Korea**

> People found with Christian Bibles, which are considered to be a symbol of the west can be executed or tortured. Refugees and defectors continued to allege that they witnessed the arrests and execution of members of underground Christian churches by the regime in prior years. Due to the country's inaccessibility and the inability to gain timely information, this activity remains difficult to verify. - [Freedom of religion in North Korea](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_religion_in_North_Korea)

More on **North Korea**:

> In this totalitarian state, the only thing that North Koreans are permitted to worship is the nation's leader, Kim Jong-un. Bibles are banned and those found in possession of one, face imprisonment, torture and even death – as do up to three generations of their family. - [Source](https://www.christiantoday.com/article/6-countries-where-owning-a-bible-is-dangerous/84497.htm)

**Somalia**

> Christians residing in Somalia face constant persecution from radical Islamists and government officials. The prevalence of the Islamic extremist group, al-Shabaab means that believers often practise their faith in extreme secrecy and cannot own Bibles. - [Source](https://www.christiantoday.com/article/6-countries-where-owning-a-bible-is-dangerous/84497.htm)

**Maldives**

> The Maldives have a reputation for being a luxurious idyll but a Bible can get you into trouble in this paradise. Under the country's strict Islamic laws, importing a Bible is forbidden. There is currently no complete translation of the Bible into Dhivehi, the official language of the tropical nation. - [Source](https://www.christiantoday.com/article/6-countries-where-owning-a-bible-is-dangerous/84497.htm)

**Morocco**

> It's against the law to carry a Bible translated into Arabic in Morocco. Reports of overt Christian persecution are few but Christian children are not given a religious education. - [Source](https://www.christiantoday.com/article/6-countries-where-owning-a-bible-is-dangerous/84497.htm)

**Libya**

> Like Morocco, Libya has laws against bringing Bibles in the Arabic language into the country. The distribution of Bibles and evangelism is illegal. - [Source](https://www.christiantoday.com/article/6-countries-where-owning-a-bible-is-dangerous/84497.htm)

**Uzbekistan**

> In this Central Asian dictatorship, high penalties are imposed on those who own Bibles. Authorities are known to detain Christians found in possession of the holy book for "keeping and storing extremist materials with the purpose of further distribution." - [Source](https://www.christiantoday.com/article/6-countries-where-owning-a-bible-is-dangerous/84497.htm)

[Christian Persecution On The Rise In Uzbekistan Where Just Owning A Bible Is Illegal](https://www.christiantoday.com/article/christian-persecution-on-the-rise-in-uzbekistan-where-just-owning-a-bible-is-illegal/97157.htm)

[Open Doors](https://www.opendoorsuk.org/persecution/countries/) profiles annually 50 countries “where Christians face the most extreme persecution.”

Comment: What are the punishments for owning a bible in Saudi Arabia? Your citation only tells something about Spain and Russia.

Comment: @K-HB : indeed. The OP asked about the current situation, and as Saudi Arabia seems to be a current example, it would be good to know more about it. For example, is only the sale, distribution or promotion banned, and is it fine for foreign visitors to have a Bible in their luggage? Or can they get in trouble for mere possession?

Comment: According to https://2001-2009.state.gov/g/drl/rls/irf/2008/108492.htm and https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/SaudiArabia.html section Faith-Related Travel Issues owning a Bible may pose some risk of arbitrary punishment, but the US department of state (which is reponsible for travel warnings and such) does not specifically advise travelers not to bring a Bible and the Saudi government has stated that personal non-muslim religious possessions are tolerated.

Comment: Russia has a federal law that prohibits the Bible from being marked as extremist ([source](http://en.kremlin.ru/acts/news/50759)), yet the New World Translation is marked as extremist and is currently under ban. Many of Jehovah's Witnesses are currently being detained in Russia for this reason.

Comment: "Christian children are not given a religious education" What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @kutschkem Morocco requires publicly funded schools to give their brand of Sunni religious instruction. Other schools are permitted to choose to give Sunni religious instruction or none at all, except for certain Jewish schools that can give Jewish instruction.

Comment: @gormadoc Just to clarify this - what this is saying is "Christian children are not given a religious education _in (public and private) schools_"? Is it common for schools around the world to have Christian and Muslim religion lessons? That can't really be true for countries where one or the other is in the minority - there wouldn't be enough teachers available. Or is the issue that there is an explicit ban for private schools to have Christian religious education, which is uncommon for other countries?

Comment: @4castle My guess would be that the reasoning of the Russian authorities was something along the lines of "The Jehova's Witnesses aren't Christians due to not believing in the Holy Trinity, and their translations of the Bible include alterations to its texts that invalidate its protection under the law since they're not real Bibles".

Comment: @kutschkem The issue is that all non-Sunni religious instruction in all schools is banned, except for Jewish instruction in certain private Jewish schools. Public schools must give Sunni instruction, and while private schools can choose not to give Sunni instruction, they can't give Christian (or Hindu, Buddhist, etc.) instruction.

Comment: @nick012000 That's not the reasoning they presented, but you can read about the trial [here](https://www.jw.org/en/news/legal/by-region/russia/russia-declares-bible-extremist/) and also the appeal hearing [here](https://www.jw.org/finder?wtlocale=E&docid=802017856&srcid=share)

Comment: @nick012000 Officially, Jehovah's Witnesses are not considered a "traditional" Russian religion (Orthodox Christianity is the only Christianity considered such) and a ban on missionary work in most places and endemic corruption that encourages local officials to harass law-abiding citizens provides the means. The government doesn't like how Jehovah's Witnesses view government and military in general and also dislikes that they are US-based. The Mormon church is in a similar position there. Putin claims that he doesn't support their oppression, but who knows?

Comment: I find it hard to believe Uzbekistan is on this list.

Answer (score 11):

This article lists six countries where owning a bible is 'dangerous' :

[Six Countries . . .](https://www.christiantoday.com/article/6-countries-where-owning-a-bible-is-dangerous/84497.htm)

The six countries listed are North Korea, Somalia, Maldives, Morocco, Libya and Uzbekistan.

Of the list - North Korea, Libya and Uzbekistan are the most intolerant.

---

**China** is, in fact, 'imprisoning' people for their religious, or cultural, beliefs as reported by recent documentaries regarding the Uighurs.

[China's Cultural Persecution of Uighurs.](https://www.bloomberg.com/opinion/articles/2019-07-16/china-s-cultural-persecution-of-the-uighurs-demands-a-response)

However the imprisonment is described by euphemisms such as 'training' and 'education'.

So also is the effort of China to stamp out Christianity.

[Preserving the Integrity of the Bible in China.](https://www.heritage.org/religious-liberty/commentary/preserving-the-integrity-the-bible-china)

> Under the direction of the Chinese government . . . a five-year plan to **reorient the Bible to promote socialism and create a new Christianity that favors the communist government’s agenda.**

Coupled with the way the Uighurs are being treated, this re-writing of the bible and the fact that bibles can no longer be retailed in China is, in effect, a genuine situation of facing potential imprisonment for possessing a real bible (as opposed to a Communist version of the bible).

Comment: Note that this answer's prime reference is actually about persecution of muslims.

Comment: @Nobody My primary reference is to six countries. My secondary reference is to the alteration of bibles. My tertiary reference refers to the deceitful way in which China imprisons people whilst claiming they are being 'educated' or 'trained'.

Comment: "Of the list, Libya and Uzbekistan are the most intolerant." More so than N. Korea? Are you absolutely sure about that?

Comment: @Mast Point taken. Edited. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

### Russia (w.r.t. non-mainstream Christianity)

The particular incident that comes to mind is the recent (2019-Sep-2) conviction of Valeriy Moskalenko, who was detained for public reading of the Bible (limited resources in English - https://jw-russia.org/en/news/19090214-1115.html is very brief description, the rest is in Russian). However, it seems that it's less about the actual acts but more about his membership of Jehovah's Witnesses, as the charges are regarding 'organizing extremist behavior' - which seems a pattern in Russia, where the Jehovah's Witnesses (and some other non-mainstream religious organizations) are treated as extremist and their acts of proselytization are restricted and punished.